# What is the "(line: String) => { }" structure known as in Scala? And how does it work?

Tags: scala

I am beginning to learn Scala, and I've run across this piece of code from https://github.com/sryza/aas/blob/master/ch05-kmeans/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/datascience/kmeans/RunKMeans.scala

```
def buildCategoricalAndLabelFunction(rawData: RDD[String]): (String => (String,Vector)) = {
   ...
   (line: String) => {
       val buffer = line.split(',').toBuffer
       ...
       val label = buffer.remove(buffer.length - 1)
       val vector = buffer.map(_.toDouble)
       ...
       (label, Vectors.dense(vector.toArray))
   }
}
```

What I don't understand is what (line: String) => {...} is doing. Where is line being initialized? It seems to me like the program is taking in line as input from the rawData argument, but I don't understand how that is happening.

If someone could explain what this Scala structure is called - or even better, how it works - I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It defines a function, using the [anonymous function syntax](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax), this is similar to arrow functions in JavaScript and other languages.

This syntax provides a way to create a function that doesn't have a name. These can be returned by other functions, assigned to variables (effectively naming them), passed to functions as parameters etc ...

Comment: Interesting... what could be the motivation for defining an anonymous function inside of a function, as shown in my original example? Is the function simply returning the anonymous function instead of a value?

Comment: Yes. See the name of your method `buildCategoricalAndLabelFunction`.

Comment: Not "instead of" a value, a function _is_ a value.